# After changes applied callback in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Where is way to do some stuff after changes applied in angular 1.5x and 2?

*(please give me answer for both versions)*

For example lets look at this snippet:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
 .module('app')
 .component('test', {
    controller: TestComponent,
    template: '' +
     '<button ng-click="$ctrl.switchTab()">Switch tab</button>' +
     '<div class="tab1" ng-if="$ctrl.tab === 1">tab 1</div>' +
     '<div class="tab2" ng-if="$ctrl.tab === 2">tab 2</div>'
  });

function TestComponent($scope, $log, $document){
  this.tab = 1;
  
  this.switchTab = function(){
     this.tab = this.tab === 1 ? 2 : 1;
  }
  
  $scope.$watch('$ctrl.tab', function(tab){
      $log.info('Looking for new active tab:', tab);
      var selector = '.tab' + tab;
      $log.info('with selector:', selector);
      var tabNode = $document[0].querySelectorAll(selector);
      $log.info('matches:', tabNode.length, 'expected: 1');
  });
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <test></test>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see result is `matches:0 expected: 1`. I want to have callback immediately after DOM updated. I don't want to use $timeout and other unpredictable methods.

Comment: It's good to show your jsfiddle to understand the main problem

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: In Angular2 you use observables or lifecycle hooks (ngOnChanges, ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit, ...)

Comment: @Loading.., snippet added.

Comment: @Phil, your solution doesn't work

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yep, but all of them fired after model change, not view.

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit()` is called after the view is updated. If the model changes and change detection is invoked manually, the view is updated sync. When  `cdRef.detectChanges()` returns, the view has been updated.